# How to get location using qml - BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, location, qml

It is possible to get longitude and latitude in BlackBerry using only qml? I found http://dengineer.com/adding-qml-gps-to-blackberry-10/ but it isnt work. Only black screen on my device. 
This is my code:

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
import QtMobilitySubset.location 1.1
Page {
    property string longitude
    property string latitude
    property variant cord
    Container {
        layout: DockLayout {}
        attachedObjects: [
            PositionSource{
                id: location
                updateInterval: 1000

                onPointChanged: {
                    cord = location.position.coordinate;
                    longitude = cord.longitude;
                    latitude = cord.latitude;
                    result.setText(longitude + " " + latitude)
                }

            }]
        Button {
            text: qsTr("Locate me")
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
            onClicked: { 
                location.start()
            }
        }
        Label {
            id: result
            text: qsTr("0 0")
            textStyle.base: SystemDefaults.TextStyles.BigText
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
        }
    }
}
```

I have error:
Jun 08 19:31:14.025    com.example.GPS_qml.testDev_ple_GPS_qml341af9aa.30007492    default    9000    WARNING     --- errors:  (file:///apps/com.example.GPS_qml.testDev_ple_GPS_qml341af9aa/native/assets//main.qml:32:13: Cannot assign to non-existent property "onPointChanged"
                onPointChanged: {
                ^)

Answer (score 1):

My understanding for QML is that it's only for display, you'll have to write some native code to do what you need. See samples at

https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Samples

you can check possibly the locationdiagnostics project giving an example of the Location API

Comment: I found something like this: http://dengineer.com/adding-qml-gps-to-blackberry-10/ but it not work. During build I have `C:\bbndk\host_10_1_0_132\win32\x86\usr\bin\ntox86-ld: cannot find -lQtLocation
make[2]: Leaving directory C:/Users/Krzysztof/ndk-10.1.0-workspace/GeoLocation_qml/x86'
cc: C:/bbndk/host_10_1_0_132/win32/x86/usr/bin/ntox86-ld caught signal 1
make[1]: Leaving directory C:/Users/Krzysztof/ndk-10.1.0-workspace/GeoLocation_qml/x86'
make[2]: *** [o-g/GeoLocation_qml] Error 1
make[1]: *** [debug] Error 2
make: *** [Simulator-Debug] Error 2`

Comment: This error is after adds MOBILITY += location to my .pro file.

Comment: I believe you have the same issue as this link http://208.74.204.192/t5/Cascades-Development/Porting-Qt-project-QtLocation-errorr/td-p/2223489 check it, the solution states using MOBILITY -= location (- instead of +)

Comment: Thanks for reply. No error during building, but still black screen after running. I cant find any error.

Comment: You're checking Device Log right? I'd suggest you just eliminate some qml parts and go add one by one till you face the issue.

Comment: After run application on my simulator I cant see any log in Log Device. Device Log works for my only when I plug my device.

Comment: I haven't really used the simulator, using a test device all the time, maybe you should check your configuration, for example enable development mode on simulator if such thing exists

Comment: development mode is active. I check one more time, Log Device not work on device and simulator. I dont know what was happen. nvm. Basic problem is, that its not work.

Comment: Well maybe it is what it is, again I suggest you just follow the official samples, they are diverse and cover 90 if not 100% of what you will ever need for BB10